# The responsetext from ajax page not displaying in intended position

Tags: ajax

Im my code i get a value from an ajax page , but it is displayed in a different position than i wish to display. I would like to display it in,..

```
<tr><td>hello</td></tr>
<tr id="showajax"><td>Ajax Value is:</td><div id="ajaxhide"></div></tr>
```

here the ajax value returned is displayed somewhere else.

I had used document.getElementById('ajaxhide').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; inside javascript properly also.
The ajax value returned is like this

```
        echo '<td>'."Thanks".'</td>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the first thing is you're trying to dynamically resize the table.  It would be better to create the cell as empty to start with and then update the content.

You've also got some invalid syntax with `<div id="ajaxhide"></div>` floating outside of any table cells but inside a table row.  It's not just that it will fail validation and each browser may treat it differently, but also that when you're making the content change you're trying to insert a cell inside the div (which isn't technically allowed) which is inside a row (which also isn't technically allowed).

The solution is to use:

```
<tr id="showajax"><td>Ajax Value is:</td><td id="ajaxhide"></td></tr>
```

Now to make the AJAX update:

```
 document.getElementById('ajaxhide').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

**A word of warning on Internet Explorer**

IE considers `COL`, `COLGROUP`, `TABLE`, `TBODY`, `TFOOT`, `THEAD` and `TR` to be read only.  This means you can update a cell (`TD`, `TH`) but not the whole row and not the whole table.  In your above example you're not trying to do that... but just be aware of the limitation if your design changes.